# Activate/ Execute all options in a custom package

Tags: packages, conditionals, package-options, options

I want an option in a package I'm writing to activate all other options. What I want is something like `\usepackage[all]{mypackage}` which will activate all options in `mypackage` (including options added later). Is there an easy way to do this? Currently, my best way to do this is to create an *if* for *every* option and setting all the ifs to true for the `all` option. However, this means I cannot activate the options that don't use ifs. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{\LaTeX\ }
\makeatletter
% Some options:
\newif\if@firstoption
\DeclareOption{option1}{\@firstoptiontrue}
\newif\if@secondoption
\DeclareOption{option2}{\@secondoptiontrue}
\DeclareOption{option3}{\renewcommand{\mycommand}{\LaTeX\ is \textit{awsome}}}
% Activate all options:
\newif\if@all
\DeclareOption{all}{\@alltrue}
% Unknown options:
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\if@all
    \@firstoptiontrue
    \@secondoptiontrue
\fi

\RequirePackage{lipsum}

\if@firstoption
    \newcommand{\foo}[1]{\textit{#1}\par \lipsum[2]}
\fi
\if@secondoption
    \newcommand{\bazbaa}{\lipsum[1]}
\fi
\makeatother

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[all]{mypackage}

\begin{document}

This is a test.
\mycommand

\foo{dummy text:}

\bazbaa

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I can activate option 1 and 2 this way since they use ifs, but not option 3. Is there a way to activate option 3 without having to use an if? Also; is there a way to automaticually include new options? Say I write a new option 4:

```
\newif\if@fourthoption
\DeclareOption{option4}{\@fourthoptiontrue}
```

Is there a way to automaticually activate this when using `all` without having to manually adjust the `\if@all` like this:

```
\if@all
\@firstoptiontrue
\@secondoptiontrue
\@fourthoptiontrue % added this line manually
\fi
```

**Also related:** Say you want an option to activate *most* options, but not *all* options. Is it possible to activate all options with the exeption of one or more options? For example: say I want a package option `most` which is eqvivalent to all options (including options added in the future) except the first option. `\usepackage[most]{mypackage}` = `\uspackage[option2,option3,option4]{mypackage}`. Is this feasable?

---

I realised that some options might not be comatible with each other. Lets say that the fourth option is:

```
\if@fourthoption
\newcommand{\bazbaa}{Hello there!}
\fi
```

which would clash with option 2 (in this case the clash can be avoided by using `\providecommand` instead, but you may not be able to fix all options clashes easaly). Is there a way to not include options that would clash with other options? Perhaps by an if or something?

Comment: `\DeclareOption{all}{\ExcuteOptions{option1,option2,option3,option4}}` ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle ! Is there maybe a way to do some sort of for loop to automaticually include the options? I was thinking something like: ``for option: \ExecuteOptions{option}`` Then maybe I can tag options that clash in some way as to not include them in the for loop?

Comment: or write a local wrapper for DeclareOption that adds to the list you declare.

Comment: How do you write a local wrapper @DavidCarlisle ? I've not heard about it before.

Comment: @Vebjorn `\newcommand\myopt[2]{\xdef\myoptlist{\ifx\myoptlist\@empty\else\unexpanded\expandafter{\myoptlist},\fi\unexpanded{#1}}\DeclareOption{#1}{#2}}` and then do `\expandafter\ExecuteOptions\expandafter{\myoptlist}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the comment from David Carlisle very helpful. I did something like:

`\DeclareOption{all}{\ExcuteOptions{option1,option2,option3,option4}}`